# How to use MSBuild.ExtensionPack

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task, msbuild-4.0, msbuildextensionpack

I have to run two targets in parallel to profile iisexpress.exe using OpenCover. 
The link below relates to the information about the issue I am having.

https://github.com/sawilde/opencover/issues/92#issuecomment-5143204

This suggested to me to use Msbuild.ExtensionPack from CodePlex.

I have downloaded the source code of MSBuild Extensions.

I compiled it. I copied the MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks tasks file in to folder BuildBinaries.

I added the below lines in my projects files.

I was trying to run the ExecMultipleTasks target. But getting the below error.

error MSB4036: The "MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Framework.Parallel" task was not found. Check the following:
 1.) The name of the task in the project file is the same as the name of the task class.
 2.) The task class is "public" and implements the Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask interface.
 3.) The task is correctly declared with  in the project file, or in the *.tasks files located in the "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319" directory.

Could you please let me know how to fix this issue?

Thanks,

Venkat.

Comment: How are you referencing the extension pack in msbuild?

Comment: Hi Initially, I downloaded the source code from CodePlex and compiled it and copied the dlls to "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\ExtensionPack" folder. There seems to a problem in the way how I did it. Instead I got the installer file and installed it. It started working. Below is the line of code how I am referring to the extensionpack tasks. <Import Project="C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\ExtensionPack\4.0\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks"/>

Answer (score 1):

which version of visual studio your application is using ?, if its 32 bit of VS then install 32 bit [Extension Pack](https://github.com/mikefourie/MSBuildExtensionPack/releases) (MSBuild.Extension.Pack.4.0.12.0.zip\4.0.12.0\x86) else go for 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you open up the file C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\ExtensionPack\4.0\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks ill think you find that the path to the dll for the task MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Framework.Parallel is not correct.

```
<UsingTask AssemblyFile="$(ExtensionTasksPath)MSBuild.ExtensionPack.dll" TaskName="MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Framework.Parallel"/>
```

I imagine the variable $(ExtensionTasksPath) does not locate your build path for your version. Either copy the files into that path or change/hardcode the new path.